# Quartus Waveform File Representation

Tags: verilog, simulation, timing, waveform

I have selected the inputs as 8 bit count values that increment over time. The 8 bit value should be parallel in and parallel out. But the bits are spaced over time. Can you please explain why the representation is like this? It is a bit confusing.

My verilog code is following:

```
module wirelink (linkin, linkout);

input [7:0] linkin;
output [7:0] linkout;

wire [7:0] linkout;

assign linkout = linkin;

endmodule
```

[image: screenshot of timing simulation]

Answer (score 1):

The bits aren't spaced over time. The value is constant in all places except where the trace looks like an X. From your trace, these are occurring at intervals of 100ns, so I presume your simulation has a 10MHz clock.

The numbers are shown as a binary representation overlaid onto the waveform. If you click the little right arrow next to the name of the trace on the left hand side of your screenshot, it will expand the trace out to show the value of all the bits separately.